# How to override systemd "Conflicts=" line

Tags: linux, systemd, services, daemon

When I need to enter a non-graphical environment, I tend to use TTY1. However, I'm also starting to use SDDM as my greeter, which uses TTY1, making it unavailable for use. I've discovered that if you type `sddm --example-config`, and redirect the output to `/etc/sddm.conf`, you can then edit said file, changing `MinimumVT=`, so that it equals 8.

Here's the hard part: the systemd unit file still conflicts with `getty@tty1`. I was hoping that I could use `# systemctl edit sddm; systemctl daemon-reload` to override this. I've tried creating a new `[Unit]` section-thing with `Conflicts=`(blank/end of line), but that didn't help at all. I've also tried `Conflicts=-getty@tty1.service`, hoping that would negate this field, but that didn't work. (I've also tried using both at the same time, the former followed by the latter.) I could modify the unit file directly, but the next time SDDM is updated, I'll lose my modifications (I'm running Arch, so *everything* is updated frequently).

Is there anyway to clear the `Conflicts=` variable in systemd, or am I SOL?

Answer (score 3):

First, find out where your standard `sddm.service` file is located:

```
$ systemctl show -p FragmentPath sddm.service
FragmentPath=/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service
```

If it's under `/lib/systemd/system/`, that's as it should be. You can then just copy it to `/etc/systemd/system/` and then modify it to your heart's content: **a unit file in `/etc/systemd/system/` will automatically override any file with an identical name in `/lib/systemd/system`.**

Any distribution updates to systemd units are supposed to affect `/lib/systemd/system` only: `/etc/systemd/system` should be fully under the authority of the local system administration only. If Arch breaks this separation of responsibilities, file a bug report.

Comment: For auto-loaded units like SDDM, you may have to disable+re-enable them, like so: `systemctl disable sddm && systemctl enable sddm`. These commands should be run as root, as that's more convenient that typing your password twice.